# understanding 'your likeliest bet' and 'settle into' in context

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Could somebody rewrite the italicized sentence in a simpler way? I don't know explain what the author intended to say there.

I've looked up the meaning of the words in the title:

> Settle in (also settle into sth): to begin to feel happy and relaxed in a new situation, home, job etc. (longman-it's installed on my pc so I can't provide a link)

for likeliest bet, there was almost nothing except the similar phrase "best bet":

> safest or most reliable course of action :  surest means to a desired end :  most advantageous approach :  most satisfactory choice 
>   https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/best%20bet

I've no idea which definition would be more suitable here.

> Can we be certain that any particular employee will conform to this rule? Absolutely not. But successful businesses are built on a series of well-calculated bets, not guarantees. *And **your likeliest bet** is that your employees have already **settled into** the personalities and aptitudes that they’ll have in the future.*

Comment: Could you add a link to each of your definitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entire article, excluding the last four sentences, describes the tendency of humans to have fixed personalities and attributes during adulthood. At the end, the author shifts to business perspective, saying that employees are also likely to follow this trend. However this is not for certain. The last sentence itself says that it is most possible that the employees have already developed and maintained their permanent personalities and aptitudes.

In particular, *likeliest bet* means likeliest outcome, on which one should base his action for best results.

*settled into personalities* means develop fixed, permanent personalities that they,and others are accustomed to.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Just to make sure, basically the last sentence is saying, "Most likely your employees have already developed their permanent personalities and aptitudes"

Comment: Yes, you got it!

Comment: But in that case the author's suddenly changing the topic, which doens't make sense?

Comment: It seems like the author is transitioning to talk about the role of personality stability in businesses. Do you have the text that follows this?

Comment: Yes. here it is
Remember this whenever you are selecting
representatives of your brand, and you’ll come out ahead. Recognize
this, and you’ll understand why we recommend using the best personality
and aptitude assessment tools available to you—appropriate testing,
appropriate evaluation—to find people with the talents you’re looking
for.
Isn’t it important to hire the applicant with the best job-specific

Comment: Indeed, the author intends to use personality stability analysis as an introduction to advice on hiring people based on their current aptitudes rather than job specific experience. The first part of the paragraph is providing scientific credibility to the advice he follows up with.